# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS host "VBoxClient: The virtualbox kernel service is not running" after logging into Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, kernel-module, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Oracle VirtualBox VM 6.1 on an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS host.

The guest OS is Windows 10.

After booting up the computer and logging into my user account, I get a grey window that pops up at the top of the desktop that says: `VBoxClient: The virtualbox kernel service is not running...`

Mind you, this is without starting VirtualBox; this message just pops up almost immediately after logging into my desktop.

I can, however, start VirtualBox and run my guest OS without problems.

I have updated the Ubuntu OS several times since installing it, and I've reinstalled VB to keep it up to date.

What is causing this message to appear?

I ran `sudo grep -i virtualbox /var/log/boot.log` in the terminal and got

```
Starting VirtualBox Web Service...
[FAILED] Failed to start VirtualBox Web Service.
         Starting VirtualBox Web Service...
[FAILED] Failed to start VirtualBox Web Service.
         Starting VirtualBox Web Service...
[FAILED] Failed to start VirtualBox Web Service.
         Starting VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
[  OK  ] Started VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
```

as the output.

So, it appears that the kernel module is staring properly but not the kernel service.

When I run  `ls /etc/modules-load.d`

I get `cups-filters.conf  modules.conf` as the output.

If I open modules.conf, I get

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.
```

So, it appears that *no* kernel modules are being loaded at boot time.

I really don't know what to make of all this.

I get an error message that doesn't seem to really affect the function of VirtualBox.

But, it doesn't seem that the error message should exist because the kernel module is starting.

Though, it seems that that should not be possible as no modules are being loaded at boot time at all.

What's causing this problem, and how do I remedy it?

I don't want that message to pop up anymore.

Thanks....

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

Did some research online.

I went to my /opt folder and found a folder within for VBoxGuestAdditions.

In that folder I found an uninstall script.

I ran that script.

After rebooting, no more error message.

Done!

Comment: Did it solve VBoxGuestAdditions features such as shared clipboard?